# PLESK XML API: How to change mail account infos without deleting mail-aliases

Tags: xml, api, email, passwords, plesk

I'm trying to change/update the mail-account-information without changing/removing(?) other mail-account-settings in plesk 12.5.
In this special case I want to change the password of an account without removing it's alias[es] (or any other informations sticked to this mail-account...).

First, I tried:

```
$request = <<<EOF
<packet>
  <mail>
    <update>
      <set>
        <filter>
          <site-id>SOME ID</site-id>
          <mailname>
            <name>SOME NAME</name>
            <password>
              <value>SOME VALUE</value>
              <type>NEW PASSWORD</type>
            </password>
            <description><![CDATA[SOME DESCRIPTION]]></description>
          </mailname>
        </filter>
      </set>
    </update>
  </mail>
</packet>
EOF;
```

When I execute this, everything works fine BUT: all mail-aliases are gone! :-( What I really don't understand so far is: "why"?? I don't touch the alias(es) at all...

So the second approach I thought about was 'getting' the alias(es) first, change the password with the code above and stick the "old" alias(es) to it again.
But when I try to get the alias(es) with:

```
$request = <<<EOF
<packet>
  <mail>
    <get_info>
      <filter>
        <site-id>SOME ID</site-id>
        <name>SOME NAME</name>
      </filter>
      !!<aliases/>!!
    </get_info>
  </mail>
</packet>
EOF;

$response = $client->request($request);
var_dump($response);
```

OUTPUT: *string(int) "ok id name **mailalias1** **mailalias2** xxx off description"* (what is right so far as I have added two aliases manually)

Now I have two questions:

1.) Which way would be the best/correct one to make "my wishes happen"? ;-)

2.) How do I get single informations out of the response from PLESK (i.e.: just the alias(es) out of the string I posted as "OUTPUT")

The reference I used: http://docs.plesk.com/en-US/12.5/api-rpc/reference/managing-mail/

Thanks a lot in advance! :)
Michael

PS: Sorry for my "unpolished" english... It's a looooong time ago!

Comment: Wow. it's obviously a bug, I'll try to find workaround.

Comment: I've not found workaround for setting mail password but submit the bug report to Plesk.

Comment: Fix of this bug expecting in 12.5 update #14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe i've not get you, but this is how you can get aliases from API responce:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($output);

$result = $xml->xpath('//alias');

while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
    echo $node . "\n";
}
```